# What new scenes were added to The Iron Giant: Signature Edition?

Tags: alternate-version, the-iron-giant

The Iron Giant: Signature Edition includes some new scenes that weren't in the original movie. Since I hadn't watched the original movie in years, I wasn't sure which scenes were actually new and which ones I had forgotten over the years.

Which changes were made to the movie from the original?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two new scenes are the Giant's dream, and a brief scene between Annie and Dean in the diner, right before Dean hauls away the tractor with the bite taken out of it.

The clip that the Giant's hand watches on TV right after Hogarth says "grace" is also different. It was originally a Maypo commercial, but has been replaced with a Tommorowland clip for the Signature Edition.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what the second scene was, but I know one of them at least.

The scene when Giant and Dean are sleeping at the scrapyard and Giant dreams of robot armies was added in.